# React router (multiple page application)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement react router for multiple page application and i don't know what's problem here please help me fix it. 
so in my **App.js** i have

```
import MindControlledWheelchairclass from './components/Header/projectscontent/mindcontrolledwheelchair';

const MindControlledWheelchair= () => {
  return(
    <div>
        <MindControlledWheelchairclass/>
        <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/hardware" component={Hardware}/>
            <Router>
                <Route  path="/hardware/MindControlledWheelchair" component={MindControlledWheelchair}/>
            </Router>
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My **hardware.js** file

```
    import MindControlledWheelchairclass from "../projectscontent/mindcontrolledwheelchair";

    class Hardwarecontent extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state={
          topic:"Hardware Projects",
          projectname:"Mind Controlled Wheelchair",
        }
      }
      render() {
        const mystyle = {
          backgroundImage:"url("+ Background +")",
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
          backgroundPosition: "center",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
        }
        return (
          <div className="hardwarecontainer">
            <div className="hwrapper">
                <h1>{this.state.topic}</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="hwcontent">
              <div>
              <NavLink to="/hardware/MindControlledWheelchair">
                <div className="hwproject" id="idhardware" style={mystyle}>
                  <div className="blackup">
                    <div className="textover">
                      {this.state.projectname}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </NavLink>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Hardwarecontent;
```

and my **mindcontrolledwheelchair.js** file

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Background from '../../../images/mindcontrolled.png';
    import {BrowserRouter, Route,Switch,Link,useParams,useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';
    import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';


    const MindControlledWheelchairclass = () => {
        return (
           <div>
              <h1>MindControlledWheelchairclass </h1>
              <p>MindControlledWheelchairclass page body content</p>
           </div>
        );
    }

    export default MindControlledWheelchairclass;
```

so in **hardware.js** after clicking on div it should go to **mindcontrolledwheelchair.js**

**So the problem is** 
In url http://localhost:3000/hardware/MindControlledWheelchair

a new page should render **mindcontrolledwheelchair.js** with

```
      <h1>MindControlledWheelchairclass </h1>
      <p>MindControlledWheelchairclass page body content</p>
```

But instead it renders it's parent page which in onlick redirects to **mindcontrolledwheelchair.js** http://localhost:3000/hardware

but url changes to http://localhost:3000/hardware/MindControlledWheelchair and content remains same of http://localhost:3000/hardware

Inshort: when i clicked on div of **hardware.js** i'm expecting a new page with content of **mindcontrolledwheelchair.js** but instead it does not renders anything and only url gets updated to /mindcontrolledwheelchair.
**HOPE YOU UNDERSTAND WHAT I MEAN**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrapping the routes incorrectly. You should not use Router in your switch statemtents. Instead you should use it just once.

With react-router-v5, you can simply do it like this:

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/hardware/MindControlledWheelchair" component={MindControlledWheelchair}/>
      <Route path="/hardware" component={Hardware}/>          
      <Route component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
```

This will render `Hardware`, if the url is `/hardware` but `MindControlledWheelchair` if the url has the `MindControlledWheelchair` tag.

The order of the statements is important. Like any switch statement, it will execute the first match. So that if `/hardware/MindControlledWheelchair` matches, it will render that. And only if that does not match, it will try to check for the `/hardware` url.

If you put the `<Route path="/hardware" component={Hardware}/>` before, it will match all `/hardware` routes and `/hardware/MindControlledWheelchair` will never be reached.

If you want to render hardware for only `/hardware` you could also add the exact boolean to the `/hardware` Route.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `/hardware/MindControlledWheelchair` matches `/hardware`. You need to use `exact` keyword for `hardware` route. So your routes would become something like:

```js
 <Route exact path="/hardware" component={Hardware}/>
     <Router>
         <Route path="/hardware/MindControlledWheelchair" component={MindControlledWheelchair}/>
     </Router>
 <Route component={NotFound}/>
```

Comment: You should not have multiple Router components though.